# WebRTC for android

Tags: android, webrtc

I am looking for achieving webrtc on android device. I wish to to video chat between android devices.

i found this link http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started

the source code is here :  http://code.google.com/p/webrtc/

But i couldnt build it properly.

Let me know if anyone has followed for building it for Android device.

advice me the issues involved.

1. Take source code
2. use Linux with android sdk
3. build the source code.
4. generate the apk.

any support in this will be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like Google is in the process of porting WebRTC. See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161417

Comment: link is not working (403)

Comment: If you still need it, I have maintained a complete tutorial to solve all the issues. You can also visit this reference article: [Compile_WebRTC_Library_For_Android](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Compile_WebRTC_Library_For_Android)

Answer (score 2):

I have build webrtc for android recently.

Very important before you start:

1. linux 64-bit (I have tr
2. java 6 (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jdk-6u45-oth-JPR)
3. ant
4. depot-tools
5. git svn

If you have all this istalled, you can just follow the steps from http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started (building for android)

You don't have to download and install ndk and sdk. It will be checkouted and set up with the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Getting WebRTC to compile for Android is not easy. The most easiest way to do this is using PristineIO scripts.

I've outline the steps I took on https://crushingday.wordpress.com/2015/01/24/getting-started-with-webrtc-building/